# Java - exiting screensaver programmatically on Windows 8/10

Tags: java, windows, screensaver, keystroke

I am looking for a method to programmatically initiate a trigger to exit the active screensaver from a Java application.

In Windows 7, I used the key strokes using Java Robot class to exit the active screensaver. This method no longer works on Windows 8/10.

is there any other way to do it?

Comment: You can try with JNI, take a look at this [post](http://www.coderanch.com/t/333688/GUI/java/Sending-key-strokes-Windows-App) on coderanch. From the technique he used you can search for any running program and sends a enter to it `"~"` like he explainded on his post.

Comment: The keystroke itself is executed properly using the Robot class(i use windows key + D to minimize all the application from my java application), however it does not exit the screensaver.

Comment: Have you tried moving mouse?

Comment: Yes, it did not help. I wonder what is the difference between Windows 8 and earlier versions of Windows screensaver, Could this be part of security update made to newer windows versions.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with a windows batch file. The batch file is executed from java process.

The batch file is reading the name of active screen saver from the registry, and killing that process using taskkill command.

Here is the .bat file content

```
rem active screensaver name from the registry
FOR /F "tokens=2* delims=    " %%A IN ('REG QUERY "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop" /v SCRNSAVE.EXE') DO SET screensaver=%%B
ECHO screensaver=%screensaver%

rem the screensaver name contains the absolute path 
rem extract only the name
Set filename=%screensaver%
For %%A in ("%filename%") do (
    Set Folder=%%~dpA
    Set Name=%%~nxA
)
echo.Folder is: %Folder%
echo.Name is: %Name%

rem kill the screensaver process
taskkill /im %Name% /f
```